# How to simply launch Outlook's new appointment window with some prefilled data in JAVA?

Tags: java, outlook, appointment

We can launch Outlook' email by simply using:

*Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new java.net.URI("mailto:YourEmailAddress@gmail.com?subject=TEST"));*

Is there a similar way to launch an Outlook's new appointment window with some data prefilled? (Not send the new meeting request, just launch the form).

Answer (score 0):

You can use COM from Java under Windows ([Jacob](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project)) - create an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object and call `CreateItem`.

In VB (easy to convert to Java):

```
set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set appt = app.CreateItem(1)
appt.Subject = "test appointment"
appt.Body = "Test body"
appt.Start = #08/27/2022#
appt.Display()
```

Comment: I tried:
**ActiveXComponent ol = new ActiveXComponent("Outlook.Application");**

But it gives error: 

_ERROR [com.calypso.AWTUNCAUGHT] [-] [] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jacob.com.ComThread_
Though I have the jacob.jar in my buildpath

Comment: Do you know any other way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't use Java, but is jacob.dll visible to the current process? See https://www.google.com/search?q=java+ActiveXComponent+NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: I am using this instead: Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("outlookcal:addevent?subject=test")) But here the problem is I cannot find other parameters like allDay=true does not work and also body/content/description/summary none of them works for body.

Comment: The url is very limited at what it can do. Do use COM automation.